# Unchecked cast: 'java.io.Serializable' to 'java.util.ArrayList<com.icresp.campex.wmo.Model.Department>'

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, android-intent

Unchecked cast: 'java.io.Serializable' to 'java.util.ArrayList'

My Code is This:

**Activity.java**

```java
ArrayList<Department> departments = new ArrayList<>();

Intent i = getIntent();
departments = (ArrayList<Department>) i.getSerializableExtra("DepartmentList");
```

**Department.java**

```java
public class Department implements Serializable {
    private int department_id;
    private String dept_name;
    private ArrayList<Course> courses;
    private ArrayList<Batch>batches;

    public Department() {
    }

    public ArrayList<Batch> getBatches() {
        return batches;
    }

    public void setBatches(ArrayList<Batch> batches) {
        this.batches = batches;
    }

    public int getDepartment_id() {
        return department_id;
    }

    public void setDepartment_id(int department_id) {
        this.department_id = department_id;
    }

    public String getDept_name() {
        return dept_name;
    }

    public void setDept_name(String dept_name) {
        this.dept_name = dept_name;
    }

    public ArrayList<Course> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }

    public void setCourses(ArrayList<Course> courses) {
        this.courses = courses;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return dept_name;
    }

}
```

The application is working well, but I get the following message:

> Unchecked cast: 'java.io.Serializable' to 'java.util.ArrayList' Inspection info: Signals places where an unchecked warning is issued by the compiler, for example:
>
> void f(HashMap map) {
>           map.put("key", "value");
>         }
>
> Hint: Pass -Xlint:unchecked to javac to get more details.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Can you please explain this in a bit details.

Comment: Make sure your `Department` class `implements Serializable`

Comment: Unchecked cast: 'java.io.Serializable' to 'java.util.ArrayList<com.icresp.campex.wmo.Model.Department>'
 this is not an error this warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Model class Department should implements Selializable like below

```
public class Department implements Serializable {
private String itemName;
public Department(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }
 String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }
}
```

Hope it will work. please try it

Comment: what is this SpaceItem

Comment: sorry it will be Department.. i have already edited.pls check.. If i works then pleaze tik my answer